# How to center a long line in the align environment

Tags: math-mode, horizontal-alignment, align

I'm having troubles (again!) with some equations alignments.  See the following MWE:

```
    \documentclass[11pt,letterpaper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[total={6in,10in},left=1.5in,top=0.5in,includehead,includefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\noindent
Blablabla bla bla blabla bla blabla bla bla blablabla blabla bla blabla bla bla bla bla blabla:
\begin{align*}
    A &= BBB \\
    = CCCC \text{to be centered on the whole line} CCCC & \\
    &= DDD.
\end{align*}
Blablabla bla bla blabla bla blabla bla bla blablabla blabla bla blabla bla bla bla bla blabla:

\end{document}
```

Preview:

[image]

As shown in red on the picture, I need the first and third lines to be aligned with their equal sign, *approximately* at the center of the page (as it is usually done within the align environment), while the second line should be centered (not aligned with the first and third lines).

The second line is what gives me the trouble.

How can I do that without cheating and hacking a lot with many `\phantom` or `\mathclap` commands?

Comment: you could use \intertext{\centering $CC=....$}` but it will be confusing to read.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, I was thinking about using the \intertext command, but it would be inapropriate.  The second line is actually a big matrix!  And I need it to be centered on the page.

Comment: It is only inappropriate because its inappropriate to align two out of three related = which is what you are asking for. I I was going to post exactly the same answer as AboAmar with shortintertext but he/she beat me to it.

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[total={6in,10in},left=1.5in,top=0.5in,includehead,includefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\noindent
Blablabla bla bla blabla bla blabla bla bla blablabla blabla bla blabla bla bla bla bla blabla:
\begin{align*}
    A &= BBB
    \shortintertext{\centering${} = CCCC$ to be centered on the whole line $CCCC$}
    &= DDD.
\end{align*}
Blablabla bla bla blabla bla blabla bla bla blablabla blabla bla blabla bla bla bla bla blabla:

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use and equation environment inside an `\intertext` command.

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[total={6in,10in},left=1.5in,top=0.5in,includehead,includefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\noindent
Blablabla bla bla blabla bla blabla bla bla blablabla blabla bla blabla bla bla bla bla blabla:
\begin{align*}
    A &= BBB 
    \intertext{\[ = CCCC \text{to be centered on the whole line} CCCC \]}
    &= DDD.
\end{align*}
Blablabla bla bla blabla bla blabla bla bla blablabla blabla bla blabla bla bla bla bla blabla:

\end{document}
```

[image]

However the vertical spacing looks a little weird and should be adjusted.

Comment: I don't think that \intertext is appropriate in my case.  My second line is actually a big matrix, and I need it to be horizontally centered on the page.  Maybe some trick with \mathclap would do, but I'm yet unable to get it right.

Comment: @Cham what objection do you have to intertext (given that for some unexplained reason you want to break the alignment)?

Comment: I need to break the alignment because the second line is too large (a big matrix).  And I need the last line to be aligned with the first one, especially since there are more lines under the last one (the code above is just a MWE).

Comment: But if ``\intertext`` is not appropriate, what kind of layout are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Vincent, I need all lines to be aligned with their equal sign, except for the second line which needs to be centered.

Comment: But how is it not achieved with ``\intertext``?

Comment: @Vincent, vertical spacings are all messed up with \intertext, in this case.